# Texpad do not find chapter image on Mac

Tags: latex, pdflatex

I am using a latex template I found on Overleaf ([link](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/the-legrand-orange-book-template-english/jtctyfmnpppc)). Using directly Overleaf, I do not have any problem when compiling. Same when using [Sublime Text](https://www.sublimetext.com). However, when using [Texpad](https://www.texpad.com), I got the following error:

```
LaTeX Warning: File `chapter_head_1.pdf' not found on input line 100.
./main.tex:100: Package pdftex.def Error: File `chapter_head_1.pdf' not found: 
using draft setting.
```

In the beginning, I thought the problem was related to [Sandboxing](https://www.texpad.com/docs/apps/getting-started/platform-specifics/sandboxing?platform=macos), but I granted already accessibility to the whole folder, so it does not make sense to me that Texpad cannot find the file.

As additional information: I am using the latest version of Texpad v1.8.15 for macOS Catalina v.10.15.6.

I really like some features offered on Texpad, so I would appreciate it very much if you could let me know how to solve this problem. Thanks!

**Update**: <Sept. 30th, 2020> Find the .log in this [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vxg0uL5TmHfTQPfSj-1Cd2BvNtCC6y9E/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: Can you show your .log file?

Comment: Hello! Yes, I made an update on the post, find there the link to the log file.